# MultiValueDictKeyError at /students/exam/1/ 'choice_pk2'

Tags: django

I loop through a radio button in order to get the value of the picked option. But, whenever an option is not picked I will get this error. How do, I send the unpick option to **NULL** or False.

```
try:
    choice_pk = [request.POST['choice_pk{}'.format(q)] for q in question_pk]
except MultiValueDictKeyError:
    choice_pk = False

if request.method == 'POST':

     question_pk = request.POST.getlist('question_pk', False)             
     choice_pk = [request.POST['choice_pk{}'.format(q)] for q in question_pk]
     '''
     try:
        choice_pk = [request.POST['choice_pk{}'.format(q)] for q in question_pk]
    except MultiValueDictKeyError:
        choice_pk = False
    '''   

    #print(marks_obtainable.marks_obtained)
    #zipped = zip(question_pk, choice_pk)
    with transaction.atomic()
```

[image]

Comment: If u want false as default: `request.POST.get('choice_pk{}'.format(q), False)` if u want null as default: `request.POST.get('choice_pk{}'.format(q))`

Comment: How should I loop through questions_pk. Or, where should I put q in question_pk